# Splitting xml document based on a child node

Tags: xslt

I want to split an xml document using an XSLT (version 2.0/3.0  supported), based on a child node. in the example provided below, it should be based on Item node.

Basically, when we split, the Item node will carry all the ancestors above it, but not the root element.

```
<Root>
    <List>
        <Header>
            <test1>a</test1>
        </Header>
        <Order>
            <Item>
                <ItemNumber>
                    <Number>1</Number>
                </ItemNumber>
            </Item>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <Item>
                <ItemNumber>
                    <Number>2</Number>
                </ItemNumber>
            </Item>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <Item>
                <ItemNumber>
                    <Number>3</Number>
                </ItemNumber>
            </Item>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <Item>
                <ItemNumber>
                    <Number>4</Number>
                </ItemNumber>
            </Item>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <Item>
                <ItemNumber>
                    <Number>5</Number>
                </ItemNumber>
            </Item>
        </Order>
    </List>
</Root>
```

Output Required is -

```
<Root>
    <List>
        <Header>
            <test1>a</test1>
        </Header>
        <Order>
            <Item>
                <ItemNumber>
                    <Number>1</Number>
                </ItemNumber>
            </Item>
        </Order>
    </List>
    <List>
        <Header>
            <test1>a</test1>
        </Header>
        <Order>
            <Item>
                <ItemNumber>
                    <Number>2</Number>
                </ItemNumber>
            </Item>
        </Order>
    </List>
    <List>
        <Header>
            <test1>a</test1>
        </Header>
        <Order>
            <Item>
                <ItemNumber>
                    <Number>3</Number>
                </ItemNumber>
            </Item>
        </Order>
    </List>
    <List>
        <Header>
            <test1>a</test1>
        </Header>
        <Order>
            <Item>
                <ItemNumber>
                    <Number>4</Number>
                </ItemNumber>
            </Item>
        </Order>
    </List>
    <List>
        <Header>
            <test1>a</test1>
        </Header>
        <Order>
            <Item>
                <ItemNumber>
                    <Number>5</Number>
                </ItemNumber>
            </Item>
        </Order>
    </List>
</Root>
```

The XSLT, I have tried is as mentioned below, I am getting same number of Items in the output (all the Items are getting repeated, instead of the desried one)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="List/Order/Item">
                <xsl:copy-of select=" ancestor-or-self::List | Order"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want

```
<xsl:template match="Order">
  <List>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../Header">
    <xsl:copy-of select=".">
  </List>
</xsl:template>
```

plus a top-level rule to construct the `Root` element.

Not sure why you call this transformation "splitting".

Comment: Thanks, this is really great, just a question, what if there was a level above header, say header was something like  <Wrap1>
 <Wrap2>
  <Header>
   <test1>a</test1>
  </Header>
 </Wrap2>
</Wrap1>                   And I want to copy <Wrap1> (all the nodes inside it)

Comment: Just add extra template rules for the additional elements. You might want to change the default template rule (in 3.0 use `<xsl:mode on-no-match="..."/>`) and only add explicit rules for elements that differ.